# Binary and Decimal converting

Tags: c, binary, decimal

When converting 0.375 to binary number I get 0.011 isn't that false? I know that binary data only contain 0 or 1 but not a point (.)!

Comment: What do you expect it to be instead? 2^-2 + 2^-3 = 0.375.

Comment: What's the standard IEEE 754 ? Check this page out `https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html`

Comment: Seems right to me. Bit weights are `4 2 1 . 0.5 0.25 0.125`

Comment: @user3386109 I just read that binary numbers only contain zeros and ones so how could that be even possible? like this 01010111

Comment: @Ahmad a typical binary integer will only have ones and zeros, however there are standards for floating point binary, which may or may not have a decimal point depending on the standard.

Comment: @Ahmad The only digits they contain are `0` and `1`.  They still contain a binary point, even for integers.  E.g. the binary integer `101` is implicitly `101.0`.  With no fractional bits, a binary number represents an integer, just as a decimal number with no fractional digits does.  So when converting `0.375` to binary, it *has* to contain fractional bits.  Otherwise it would be an integer, which would clearly be incorrect.

Comment: `0.375` in decimal is `3/8`, and `0.011` is also 3 eighths when interpreted as binary.  That looks right to me.

Comment: This really seems more like a basic math question than a programming question.  It doesn't really have anything to do with C.

Comment: This might help (it would show you how to convert `0.011` back to decimal):  [How to convert binary fraction to decimal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866393/how-to-convert-binary-fraction-to-decimal)

Comment: @Ahmad It's just a matter of convention. Most of the time binary numbers are used to represent whole numbers. But you can also use binary encodings for [fixed-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) and [floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). The encoding is still just 0's and 1's, but there is an implicit decimal point.

Comment: Think of it as a *fractional* point. Just as the digits to the left of the point represent units of base^0, base^1 etc, the digits on the right of the point represent units of base^-1, base^-2 etc.

Comment: @user3386109 Not a decimal point.  The correct term is *binary point*.  It's base 2, not 10, remember?  I explained this in my previous comment.

Comment: @Ahmad how would you propose keeping track of the fractional portion of the binary number?

Comment: @TomKarzes in this case, but it's whatever the number base is.

Comment: @WeatherVane Right.  But strictly speaking, only base 10 numbers have a "decimal" point.  Perhaps "fractional point" would be a better term, decoupling the concept from the specific number base.

Comment: @TomKarzes that's why I called it a *fractional* point in my first comment. The digits following represent fractions of whatever number base.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, it's a better term.  Although when dealing specifically with binary numbers, the term "binary point" is commonly used.

Comment: It's actually a [radix point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point). If you insist on nitpicking, at least get it right.

Comment: @user3386109 Oh, nice, yes that seems to be the exact base-independent term.  Although I never specifically cited "fractional point" as a real term.  I merely suggested that it might be better.  The same was true for Weather Vane's comment.

Comment: What does this have to do with C?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Nothing.  It's not a programming question, it's a basic math question.

Answer (score 3):

> When converting 0.375 to binary number I get 0.011 isn't that false?

No, actually.

> I know that binary data only contain 0 or 1 but not a point (.)!

Binary numbers do only contain 0 or 1 because they are base 2. Base 2 means that the maximum number you can represent with any digit is 2^1 - 1 or 1. But this has nothing to do with representing the fractional portion of a base 2 number. The fractional portion of the number is represented after the "point" which is actually called [a radix point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point). And this applies to all number bases.